# Why is the distance between plus or minus and the number different?

Tags: kerning

In the align below the last element of the first row is slightly off compared to the next rows. It looks like the root cause is mostly the distance between minus and zero, but also between the equal sign and minus. Why are they so different?

```
\begin{align}
\cee{Fe^2+_{(aq)} + 2e- -> Fe_{(s)}&(reduction) &E^0&= -0.41V}\\
\cee{Al_{(s)} -> Al^3+_{(aq)} + 3e- &(oxidation) &E^0&= +1.66V}\\
\cee{3Fe^2+_{(aq)} + 2Al_{(s)} -> 2Al^3+_{(aq)} + 3Fe_{(s)}&(overall) &E_{cell}&= +1.25V}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: If you know Italian, see this: https://youtu.be/VPsS5_b5U30

Comment: Completely off topic to your question, but relevant for how you deal with your text later on: seeing that you align the equals signs and the descriptive parentheses, I, as a reader of chemistry texts, would like to request that you *please align the reaction arrows as well*. This is a completely personal opinion, but I find it easier (and more beautiful) to read reactions where the arrows are aligned (do keep the other alignments you have already).

Comment: @Mrkvička: I've added that option in [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352832/5764).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`+` and `-` have special meaning within `\cee` since it relates to charges of atoms/particles and is therefore treated differently. The `-` visually defaults to a *unary* minus while `+` defaults to a binary relation (for joining atoms in a reaction). In this instance one can force it to be unary using `{+}`, as in `E^0 &= {+}1.66V`.

Here is an alternative with some adjusted horizontal alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\newcommand{\BRR}{\makebox{\phantom{\cee{2Al^3+_{(aq)} + 3Fe_{(s)}}}}}

\begin{document}

Adjusted alignments:
\begin{align}
  \cee{        Fe^2+_{(aq)} + 2e-} & \cee{ -> Fe_{(s)}                 } && \text{(reduction)} &             E^0 &= -0.41V \\
  \cee{                  Al_{(s)}} & \cee{ -> Al^3+_{(aq)} + 3e-       } && \text{(oxidation)} &             E^0 &= +1.66V \\
  \cee{ 3Fe^2+_{(aq)} + 2Al_{(s)}} & \cee{ -> 2Al^3+_{(aq)} + 3Fe_{(s)}} && \text{(overall)}   & E_{\text{cell}} &= +1.25V
\end{align}

Using \verb|\phantom|s:
\begin{align}
  \cee{ \llap{\cee{Fe^2+_{(aq)} + 2e-}} -> \rlap{\cee{Fe_{(s)}}} \BRR} & 
    \text{ (reduction)} &      E^0 &= -0.41V \\
  \cee{           \llap{\cee{Al_{(s)}}} -> \rlap{\cee{Al^3+_{(aq)} + 3e-}} \BRR} & 
    \text{ (oxidation)} &      E^0 &= +1.66V \\
  \cee{                     3Fe^2+_{(aq)} + 2Al_{(s)} -> 2Al^3+_{(aq)} + 3Fe_{(s)}} & 
    \text{ (overall)}   & E_{\text{cell}} &= +1.25V
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Due to the right-left alignment of `align`, we push the reactions over by the width of the maximum of the right hand side (or `2Al^3+_{(aq)} + 3Fe_{(s)}`).

Comment: No, the reason is very different. If you try a simple `\begin{align}A&=-2\\B&=+2\end{align}`, you can see what I mean.

Comment: @egreg: True, `\cee` influences the way `+` (and `-`) functions; I'll re-word.

Answer (score 23):

The reason is that `\cee` does a different scanning than usual and gets tricked by `+`, which *does* have a special meaning inside `\ce` or `\cee`, because it's used for reactions.

Indeed, if you try putting that part outside `\cee` (which it should be), the problem doesn't show.

Here's a better version.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{retain-explicit-plus}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
E&=-0.1\\
F&=+0.1
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  \cee{Fe^2+_{(aq)} + 2e- -> Fe_{(s)} &\ (reduction)}  & E^0 &= \SI{-0.41}{\V} \\
  \cee{Al_{(s)} -> Al^3+_{(aq)} + 3e- &\ (oxidation)} & E^0 &= \SI{+1.66}{\V} \\
  \cee{3Fe^2+_{(aq)} + 2Al_{(s)} -> 2Al^3+_{(aq)} + 3Fe_{(s)} & \ (overall)} &
    E_{\mathrm{cell}} &= \SI{+1.25}{\V}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]